# Getting All data from specific column in SQLITE Android

Tags: android, sqlite

There is android sqlite database with one table, im using this query for getting values :

```
        Cursor cursor = db.query(Table_Items, null, "type=? AND operationtype=? AND problemtype=?",
            new String[] { roosazi,type,problem }, null, null,KEY_Items_ID+" "+date , null);
```

everything is working fine.
question is:
how can i get all from specific column? let me give an example:
all values with type="A" and operationtype="XYZ" are needed , no matter what problemtype is! of course i can use something like this :

```
        Cursor cursor = db.query(Table_Items, null, "type=? AND operationtype=?",
            new String[] { roosazi,type }, null, null,KEY_Items_ID+" "+date , null);
```

but problem is sometimes problemtype is X and sometimes its like ALL!

how can i achieve this? can i put something like * instead of problem?

thank u so much

Comment: Can u try and rewrite teh question because i didnt understand what u want/need to do

Comment: @EE66 the question is :
how can i get all values on a table independent from specific column ,
here I'm filtering three columns :
new String[] { roosazi,type,problem }
how can i ignore PROBLEM without removing it from query! means , is there any special character or something to ignore the effect of PROBLEM? since sometimes i need it , sometime i don't need it! it the same story for all of these 3 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to use the same query to get sometimes with a particular problem type like X,Y or Z, and sometimes with any problem type,

If that is the case you could use the statement 'like' in your query instead of '=' in the problemtype field

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(Table_Items, null, "type=? AND operationtype=? AND problemtype like '?'",
```

When you want to return all values just past

problem = "%"

% simbol means any characters,

When you want to return values with a particular problem use

problem = "X"

in the values array

```
 new String[] { roosazi,type,problem }
```